# ntheorem and LyX (with amsmath)

Tags: lyx, amsmath, ntheorem

Recently, I tried to use the `ntheorem` package with `LyX` and `amsmath`, but when compiling (pdflatex format) it complains:

"*! Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined.*"

When exporting the .lyx file to "latex simple" format, I see that LyX loads `amsthm` automatically, obviously that is the conflict (If I delete the "offending" load, it runs ok).

Does anyone know any workaround? (different from "don't use LyX!", because I find it comfortable, writing a lot of mathematics, not seeing as many "$", etc.)

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  "Lyx" is the front end.  To do anything, it has to use a `\documentclass`, and that is what is almost certainly loading `amsthm`.  What `\documentclass` is being used?  You may need to specify a different one.

Comment: I do not know how you are initialising Lyx but if you have a custom template or the document you are having difficulty then set `Document Settings` `Math Options` `amsmath` `Do not load` save the file as an easy to remember name such as  ntheoremNOamsMath :-) and use it as your future default for ntheorem